# Calling an external PHP file within a local JavaScript file?

Tags: php, javascript, html, external

I have an HTML form on my website that submits all the information (after pressing submit) while remaining on the same page. A JavaScript file enable this, so after you fill it out and press submit, the module fades and says thank you for submitting your info, all while remaining on that same page.

Now in that JS that enables the function, I have to call the actual PHP that sends the form.

When it was internally located on my server, that line of code looked like this:

```
 var result= postData(data,'./form.php"');      
 if (result !=null){
     $('#form').html('<img src="./images/thankyou.png"></img>');
```

Now this worked perfectly. I had to move that PHP to another server at http://www.somesite.com/php/action.php

How could I call that PHP? I tried

```
var result= postData(data,'http://www.somesite.com/php/form.php"');
```

and it does work. What is the easiest way to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

This is what you would use AJAX for.  These answers assume you're working on the same domain.

## The easy way

The easiest way to use AJAX is to use jQuery, however this is not strictly necessary (see below).  http://www.queness.com/post/160/create-a-ajax-based-form-submission-with-jquery

Generic sample:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

## The less easy way

If you didn't want to use jQuery, you can do without it.  http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/ajax_forms/index.html

Sample HTML

```
<p><html><br/>
<head><br/>
<title>Form Posts with Ajax</title><br/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Ajax.js"></script><br/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Post.js"></script><br/>
</head><br/><br/>
<body><br/><br/>
<form action="bridge.php" method="post" onsubmit="Post.Send(this); return false;"><br/>
Name:<br/><input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
<br/><br/><br/>
Message:<br/><textarea name="message"></textarea><br/>
<br/><input type="submit" value="submit" /><br/>
</form><br/><br/>
</body><br/>
</html></p>
```

Sample JavaScript

```
    var Ajax = new Object();
    Ajax.isUpdating = true;
    Ajax.Request = function(method, url, query, callback)
    {
        this.isUpdating = true;
        this.callbackMethod = callback;
        this.request = (window.XMLHttpRequest)? new XMLHttpRequest(): new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        this.request.onreadystatechange = function() { Ajax.checkReadyState(); };
        if(method.toLowerCase() == 'get') url = url+"?"+query;
        this.request.open(method, url, true);
        this.request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        this.request.send(query);
    }
    Ajax.checkReadyState = function(_id)
    {
        switch(this.request.readyState)
        {
            case 1: break;
            case 2: break;
            case 3: break;
            case 4:
                this.isUpdating = false;
                this.callbackMethod(this.request.responseXML.documentElement);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Loading up jQuery for AJAX seems like an overkill.

Comment: So you are saying I need to redo my entire form? There is no simple way around this?

Comment: @user755889 No, your form should not have to be changed.  You simply need to add some JavaScript to intercept the submit and send it using AJAX.  Please see the links I posted.

Comment: @Francisc - I would hope that he's not building a website that just submits a form and that's it. Most developers employed in  development professionally are most likely building complex applications, which means there is a plethora of opportunities to take advantage of the power and speed of jQuery. If this is just an academic exercise where one is simply submitting a form and nothing else, then sure, sticking to JS can be a great learning experience.

Comment: That's just speculation. So is this: it could very well just be a website that submits a form, maybe it's just a mini landing page. Or just the contact page of a static website etc.

Comment: It's more speculation, and naive, to honestly believe that he just has a form and nothing else... I mean nothing else, nothing whatsoever that could make his job faster and easier. Take for instance the function that fades out his module and replaces it with thank you. I'm sure he took the time to write his own fadeout function instead of reusing existing code... That's faster to reinvent the wheel, right?

Comment: @Francisc: For me, using 'normal' javascript in this case instead of the ease and simplicity and elegance and extensibility jQuery offers, seems like overkill. You can easily link to for instance Google's CDN library (only about 90 KB for latest minified version) and there's a good chance your visitors have already loaded jQuery from this CDN in any case.  Furthermore you are then set to use it for other effects as well, should it be required in future.  Even if you are an expert in 'pure' javascript your development time, effort and code size will struggle to compare with jQuery development.

Comment: There are libraries that deal with AJAX alone if you don't want to write vanilla JavaScript (although once you've written it, you have it). Commodity is no excuse.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to submit form data from one domain context to another server. You can do this using JSONP, or cross domain JavaScript.

```
function sendFormData(urlToSendTo) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", urlToSendTo);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

$('form').click(function() {
    src="http://www.example.com/php/action.php?name=" + $(this).find('[name="name"]').val() + "&email=" + $(this).find('[name="email"]');
    sendFormData(src);
    return false;  // if this doesn't work, try event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you are indeed trying to send data from a webpage loaded at http://domain.com to a PHP page hosted on http://example.com, this is the only way you can send the data to the server without reloading the page. If the PHP page is on the same server, then the other solution that was posted by @msigman will work.

Comment: What's with the cowardly downvote? Come out of hiding and explain what you think is wrong with this :)

Comment: I also got a mysterious downvote... Maybe someone was just having a bad day.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this way:

In your local server: `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/external/php/file"></script>`

And modify the php file:

```
 <?
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
//your php codes here as normal
//your dispalying resoursec here in this format: echo "document.write(\"what you want to display\")";
?>
```

This external php file will output a javascript file to your local server.